# Incompatible Types in Initialization

Tags: objective-c, types

I have the following code in a subroutine that produces an incompatible types in initialization error on the varVal library in the subroutine evaluateExpression:

```
NSDictionary *varVal;

for (int i=0; i<varCount; i++) { 
    [varVal setObject:[(i+1)*2 stringValue] forKey:[i stringValue]]; 
}

double result =[[self brain] evaluateExpression:[[self brain] expression]
usingVariableValues:varVal];
```

My subroutine declaration in the brain.h file is:

```
    +(double)evaluateExpression:(id)anExpression
    usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variables;
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You keep trying to send messages to `int`s. That is categorically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`+(double)evaluateExpression:(id)anExpression` is a class method not an instance method.

try

`double result =[brain evaluateExpression:[[self brain] expression] usingVariableValues:varVal];`

and as a style point classes should generally be capped for easy reading as in...

```
@interface Brain : NSObject

....

double result =[Brain evaluateExpression:[[self brain] expression] usingVariableValues:varVal];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your comment on style helped as well.